# Error encountered installing Android NDK

Tags: android, exception, android-ndk, installation

I recevied the following error(s) while installing the Android NDK:

```
...
Extracting  android-ndk-r10d/build/awk
Extracting  android-ndk-r10d/build
Extracting  android-ndk-r10d

Sub items Errors: 52776

Archive Errors: 1

Sub items Errors: 52776
[Macintosh-2:/] Naper%
```

Installing:

```
android-ndk-r10d-darwin-x86_64.bin
```

on a MacBook Pro (Lion) using Eclipse as IDE.  This same install fully completes on my MacBook Air Yosemite.

I have ran the install twice, both erring in the same spot.

I would appreciate any guidance here.  I have searched Google without finding anything on this.

Answer (score 1):

Check your disk space.
The extracted files size is usually around 3Gb

Answer (score 0):

(Sorry I can't comment)

I met the same problem when I downloaded ndk-r10d from website other than android.com.

I tried r10c and it worked. I hope it helps you.